# How to get value by id from ajax text response

Tags: javascript, ajax

below is my code, it is not working, how to data by id from response ?
please provide any solution to this issue.

```
function loadStatus(uri,id)
{
    waitingDialog.show('Loading', {dialogSize: 'sm'});
    $.ajax({
        method : "GET",
        dataType : "text",
        url : uri,
        xhrFields : {
            withCredentials : true
        },
        crossDomain : true,
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

    }).done(function(msg) {
        waitingDialog.hide();
        alert(msg);
        // getting value by id
        var contractID= $msg.filter('#contractID').text();
        // getting value by id
        var contractID=$(msg).find('#contractID').html();
        alert(contractID);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you paste msg value here. ?

Comment: `it is not working` doesn't give any clue

Comment: `header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
header['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*' `

add above code in html and than check.

Comment: This is the Text I am getting in alert pop up.........


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <input type="hidden" id="contractID" value="3" />
 <input type="hidden" id="contractedStatus" value="Contracted" />
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the type of data you are expected to get from the uri. Inside your done function you are not supposed to query a html element. Just alert msg and see what you are getting.

Comment: thanks macman ! datatype is "text" and i have already seen the alert messsage its showing the html document with html tags.

Comment: I think your data source is not correct. Is that some data returned by the uri or just another html file?

Comment: This is the Text I am getting in alert pop up.........


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <input type="hidden" id="contractID" value="3" />
 <input type="hidden" id="contractedStatus" value="Contracted" />
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Try this $( "msg" ).filter( document.getElementById( "contractID" ) );

Comment: What about $( "msg" ).filter( document.getElementById( "contractID" ) ).val();

Answer (score 0):

```
var contractID= $msg.filter('#contractID').text();
```

$msg is not defined anywhere ... next line you use

```
$(msg)
```

is that what you meant?